# How Embed a Video from Yahoo Videos or youtube to Android

Tags: javascript, android, html

How to embed a video from youtube or yahoo videos to an android application
I'm using Phonegap so mainly I'm writing javascript then the code is wrapped to be native code

But I'm only writing JS & HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want to use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) with the link pointed at the embedded video hyperlink.

Something along the lines of the following:

```
<LinearLayout ... >
     ... my content
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" ... >
        ...
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then use the following hook in the code (mostly from the WebView docs):

```
WebView webview = (WebView) activity.getViewById(R.id.webView1);

// Simplest usage: note that an exception will NOT be thrown
// if there is an error loading this page (see below).
webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");

// OR, you can also load from an HTML string:
String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
// ... although note that there are restrictions on what this HTML can do.
// See the JavaDocs for loadData() and loadDataWithBaseURL() for more info.
```

Don't forget

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in the manifest.